# How to call Swift initializer (that has a parameter) from Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a Swift class:

```
class MyTextField : NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate { 

    var myField: UITextField

    // no idea how to pass in my UITextField from Objective-C code
    init (x: UITextField) {
        myField = x;
    }
}
```

I have added a property (not shown) so I could set myField, and everything is working.

Would like to use the init function, if only the syntax were not a complete mystery. Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Call it the same way you'd call an Obj-C initializer, so for your example, you'd call `[[MyTextField alloc] initWithX:theTextField];`.

Comment: I'm still a Obj-C newbie I guess. Thanks

Comment: And init must be public I believe - at least in my experience

Comment: in swift 4+ the initializer must be declared with @objc or it won't be visible to the objective-c code: \@objc init(x:UITextField)